# How do I build Git on Solaris

Tags: git, makefile, solaris

I downloaded Git sources from:

```
https://github.com/git/git
```

and now trying to build on Solaris 10g.

I'm not sure what I need to change in the Makefile, if anything, since there is no "configure" file. When I run make I get:

```
cc: illegal option -Wall
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

I do have gcc installed but I'm not sure how to tell the Makefile to use it.

Update:

Updated the Makefile per answer below but I still can't get it to compile:

```
make
CC credential-store.o
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fprofile-correction"
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

Comment: nit: it's Solaris 10, not "Solaris 10g". That suffix is for the Oracle rdbms, not Oracle Solaris.

The answerfrom timrau re gcc is what you need, elsewise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the line 396 of [Makefile](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile#L396) into

```
CC = gcc
```

Regarding the `-fprofile-correction` issue, you could workaround it by removing the problematic option from line 1558 of [Makefile](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile#L1558).
That is, change

```
CFLAGS += -fprofile-use=$(PROFILE_DIR) -fprofile-correction -DNO_NORETURN=1
```

into

```
CFLAGS += -fprofile-use=$(PROFILE_DIR) -DNO_NORETURN=1
```

Comment: Thx, that did let me use gcc but it still won't build. Updated the question.

Comment: With this + gmake I was able to build it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/git/). You can get a working git package and the sources on how to build it.

Comment: OpenCSW version of git is slightly newer than the one from the Solaris package manager, but it is still quite old. For example, it still doesn't have the worktrees feature.

Answer (score 0):

2 years later and the current version of git is 2.9.3, yet Google sends me here for reference.

My original compile error was:

```
    LINK git-credential-store
ld: fatal: library -liconv: not found
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to git-credential-store
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2018: git-credential-store] Error 1
$
```

it compiled using (gnu make is ahead of Solaris make, in path):

```
make configure      # creates the configure script
./configure --with-iconv=/usr/local --with-openssl=/usr/local --with-zlib=/usr/local --with-python=/usr/sfw/bin
make ICONV_LINK='-L/usr/local/lib -lintl' CC=gcc
```

Compiling GNU software needs the `gmake` or equivalent.  Due to other projects, I have recent rebuilds of most all of what's found in /usr/sfw/ compiled into /usr/local, including the latest gnu make.  Found other references that iconv & gettext were interrelated, and they needed to be compiled knowing of each others' existence, so compiled each of them twice.

`INSTALL` file and `./configure --help` were insufficient references for me to follow, but they got me 90% of the way.

Not until I hit this reference, did I find the `ICONV_LINK='-L/usr/local/lib -lintl'` I needed to successfully compile.  1st time around, I followed it exactly, with all the edits, until I narrowed it down to what I posted above:
http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Compiling-git-on-Solaris-Recipe-included-td7541556.html

host & compiler:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS mysunbox 5.10 Generic_147147-26 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-1500 Solaris
$
$ gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.3/specs
Configured with: /sfw10/builds/build/sfw10-patch/usr/src/cmd/gcc/gcc-3.4.3/configure --prefix=/usr/sfw --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --without-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
$
```

Hope this helps someone! (maybe 2 more years in the future)